# Nagios webconf - Web directory

Tags: webserver, nagios

I'm following [this guide](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart-ubuntu.html).

I'm launching:
    make install-webconf

The problem is that I already have Apache2 installed in /etc/apache2 directory, but thee Nagios installer looks for /etc/httpd ..
How can I resolve it?
As newbie, I tried to change the path in Makefile, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Back before web install section in the guide, it showed a 'configure' command.  If you type './configure --help', you will see in the output:

```
  --with-httpd-conf=<path_to_conf>
                      sets path to Apache conf.d directory
```

That configure option can be used to change your path to /etc/apache2, with something like:

```
./configure --with-httpd-conf=/etc/apache2/conf.d
```